# How to call a controller function inside an if statement in web.php?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, eloquent, laravel-routing

I have a route in web.php that looks like this:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    if (Auth::user()->type === 'admin') {
        return view('adminDashboard');
    } elseif (Auth::user()->type === 'manager') {
        // Here I want to call ManagerController@managerDashboard function
    } elseif (Auth::user()->type === 'user') {
        return view('UserDashboard');
    } else return redirect('404');
})->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');
```

How can I call a controller function in that if statement?

Comment: This logic would be better performed in a controller action rather than a route definition.

Comment: @Peppermintology I'm aware of that and have used it elsewhere. Now I'm just looking to see if there's a way to perform this login in the routing itself, even if this is a worse way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are aware that there are better ways of doing this, see https://laravel.com/docs/master/redirects#redirecting-controller-actions

```
return redirect()->action([ManagerController::class, 'managerDashboard']);
```

Answer (score 1):

write all the if-else statements in the controller.

```
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->middleware(['auth'])->name('dashboard');
```

In controller create  a method name index and write the above code

```
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index(){
    if (Auth::user()->type === 'admin') {
            return view('adminDashboard');
        } 
elseif (Auth::user()->type === 'manager') {
           return view('ManagerDashboard')
        }
 elseif (Auth::user()->type === 'user') {
            return view('UserDashboard');
        } 
else return redirect('404');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use middleware to make a route group that only can be accessed by specific role, see the docs here

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware